# i needed automatically creation of AD user directory in hdfs

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

I have CLoudera 5.7 setup already integrated with Active directory, using kerberos as shown over [AD integration](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/07/new-in-cloudera-manager-5-1-direct-active-directory-integration-for-kerberos-authentication/). But the issue is that I have to create a user directory in HDFS @ /user for each user to provide access to the user to work over hadoop.
Is their any way which will automatically create user directory in hdfs as soon as the user login over edge node? As it is very difficult to create and delete user directory of 7000+ employee over cluster.

Comment: *"very difficult to create and delete user directory of 7000+ employee "* -- difficult, really?!? What about a shell script that gets the list of employees with `ldapsearch`, the list of HDFS home dirs with `hdfs dfs -ls`, and creates all missing home dirs? Plus a `cron` scheduling for periodic refresh?

Answer (score 0):

You may create `/etc/profile.d/hadoop.sh` script to automate process. This script will be always called when hadoop shell is created (i.e. hadoop command is executed).

Below is example. 

**Step 1**. Add below scriptlet to /etc/profile.d/hadoop.sh

[root@mybox tmp]# tail -n 5 /etc/profile.d/hadoop.sh

```
if [[ "$FROM_HADOOP_PROFILE" != "1" ]] 
then
    /bin/bash -x /etc/profile.d/FromHadoopProf.sh
fi
```

**Step 2**. Create FromHadoopProf.sh script to create directory for user

```
[root@mybox tmp]# cat  /etc/profile.d/FromHadoopProf.sh
#!/bin/bash

export FROM_HADOOP_PROFILE=1
uname=`whoami`
hdir=""

if [[ "$uname" == "root" ]]
then
        hdir="/root"
else
        hdir="/user/$uname"
fi

hadoop fs -ls -d $hdir
lsout=`echo $?`
echo $lsout
if [[ "$lsout" != "0" ]]
then
      echo file does not exists
      sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -mkdir $hdir
fi
```

Notes:

1. set and check for `FROM_HADOOP_PROFILE` is done to avoid recursive infinite call/execution of `FromHadoopProf.sh`
2. `/etc/profile.d/hadoop.sh` will also be called when normal shell is spawned (e.g. when user logs in to machine)
3. You may have to add some hacks to manager user permissions e.g. in my cluster , logged in user did not have permission to create directories in hadoop `/user/` directory , hence I had to execute `hadoop fs -mkdir $hdir` with sudo

Comment: thanks shubhangi for quick response.
But for creating user after enabling kerberos we have to generate ticket for hdfs using kinit which will destroy the ticket of user and that user will be authorized as hdfs user for that session. we already try this approach, but we can't able to achieve the goal as either user act as hdfs or it must have sudo access

Comment: @Prakul , please confirm if my answer serves your purpose.

Comment: @Prakul, you could also use `KRB5CCNAME` env variable to switch **temporarily** the Kerberos cache, so that the login procedure has `hdfs` privileges, but the user gets backs his/her own privileges after login has completed. The trick would be to prevent users from reverse-engineering that login script and switching again their credentials for malicious purposes.

Comment: sorry for the delay response,
yes we are able to create directory using your idea. i create a bash script and put that in /etc/profile.d for the automation according to our project requirement

Comment: Thanks for reply Prakul !

Answer (score 0):

I write the below script for creating automatic directory in hdfs for the new AD user.

```
klist >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? == 0 ]
then
hadoop fs -test -d /user/$USER >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? != 0 ]
then
noOutput=`echo "password" | kinit hdfs`
hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/$USER
hdfs dfs -chmod -R 700 /user/$USER
hdfs dfs -chown -R $USER:$USER /user/$USER
kdestroy
echo "$(tput setaf 1)enter password for creating home directory on hdfs. This is one time activity$(tput sgr 0)"
kinit $USER
fi
fi
```